# Using resistance

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conductors

I want to know the purpose of using resistance. Is it used to

- Reduce the amount of current?
- Reduce the speed of the electrons in the wires?

---

- For the first reason: Why do we just don't use a battery with less voltage and that would intuitively reduce the current ( because we can't eliminate the resistance of the wires)?
- For the second reason: If the speed becomes different, how do we use the law $I=VenA$ to estimate the current in the whole circuit while the speed is different from point to point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: "neither".

A resistance, in a circuit, causes a voltage drop for a given current. Alternatively, if the voltage is given, it causes a particular current to flow.

As soon as a circuit gets a little bit more complex (more than one battery-resistor-light bulb-switch), it becomes completely impractical to use lots of batteries to control voltages.

The "speed" of electrons is a function of the current, cross section, and number of charge carriers. It is fairly rare that that is a property we directly care about (with possible exception of Hall effect sensors and the like).

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms, resistors in electrical circuits can be used for a wide variety of applications. If we put a small resistance in series with a conductor in a circuit, and know the value of the resistance accurately then we can measure the current through that conductor by reading the voltage drop across the resistor and using Ohms law to calculate the current. In this application the resistor is often called a *shunt*.

In operational amplifier circuits, the ratio of feedback to input resistance can be adjusted to set the gain of the amplifier.

And special, temperature sensitive resistors, called thermistors can provide  a means for measuring temperature by measuring the voltage drop across the thermistor with a constant input current.

So these are just three examples of many that resistors provide by limiting current and in the process creating a voltage drop